# Android app crashed when object is added to ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, addition

I'm new to this so apologies for any mistakes.

Context: as part of the object Training, i'm trying to add an arraylist of object Exercises. However. Everytime I try to add an object Exercise to the Arraylist of Training, the app crashes.
Any help is welcome.

Objects Training and Exercise look like this

```
public class Training {
    public Integer trainingNumber;
    public Date datum;
    public Integer nrOfExercises;
    public ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
}

public class Training {
    public Integer trainingNumber;
    public Date datum;
    public Integer nrOfExercises;
    public ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
}
```

The code trying to generate all this is as follows:

```
 private Training createRandomTraining(int i){
        Training randomTraining = new Training();
        Random random = new Random();

        int d = random.nextInt(30)+1;
        int m = random.nextInt(12)+1;
        //int y = random.nextInt(21)+2000;
        int amountOfExercises = random.nextInt(9-6)+6;

        randomTraining.trainingNumber = i;
        randomTraining.datum = new Date(2021,m,d);

       for (int j = 0; j < amountOfExercises ; j ++){
            Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
            Random r = new Random();

            int set = r.nextInt(5)+1;
            int nameInt = r.nextInt(3);
            int rep = r.nextInt(12)+1;
            //int y = random.nextInt(21)+2000;

            exercise.trainingNumber = i;
            exercise.exerciseNumber = j+1;
            exercise.exerciseName = getExerciseName(nameInt);
            exercise.sets = set;
            exercise.reps = rep;
            exercise.weight = random.nextInt(200-50)+50;

            randomTraining.exercises.add(exercise); //the app crashes here.   //The other parts work fine.
         }

        randomTraining.nrOfExercises = amountOfExercises;
        return randomTraining;
    }
```

Comment: Please, could you share the error log?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a `NullPointerException`.  Your class definition of `Training` is not initializing `List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>()` so you cannot `#add` at that line in code.

Comment: It worked!! Adding List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>() before the for-loop fixed it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program crashed is because you defined a reference ("exercises") without creating an object, and then you tried to use the reference despite no object existing. Without creating an object, the value for `exercises` is null, and calling `.add()` on a null reference will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Here is a very simple example which the compiler would flag (don't need to run the program to detect the error):

```
String s;
int l = s.length();
```

If you compile that code, you should see a compilation error like this:

```
ReferenceWithoutObject.java:11: error: variable s might not have been initialized
int l = s.length();
        ^
1 error
```

Your example does this same thing, though it involves a few classes so the compiler doesn't detect the error. Here's a simple version of what you're doing, which compiles fine:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ReferenceWithoutObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Training training = new Training();
        training.exercises.add(new Exercise());
    }
}

class Training {
    public List<Exercise> exercises;
}

class Exercise {
}
```

If you run that code, it produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "training.exercises" is null
    at ReferenceWithoutObject.main(ReferenceWithoutObject.java:6)
```

There are a few ways to fix this, but a simple one: create an actual list using `new ArrayList<>()`, and assign it to your `exercises` reference, like this:

```
class Training {
    public List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Also, you'll notice that I modified the code to define `public List<Exercise> exercises` instead of `public ArrayList<Exercise> exercises` – that is, to declare `exercises` using an interface (`List`) instead of a concrete class (`ArrayList`). It's good practice to define variables using interfaces rather than concrete classes.